# How do I use these dried wood pieces from Thailand?

Tags: thailand, translations

I bought this bag of chipped wood (?) in a store with natural health remedies in Bangkok. I can't remember what wood they are made of and how do you use them.

The Thai words on the packaging are of little help as I can't either translate or read them.

Can aynone either translate this into English or at least help me find out what is it and how do I use it?

[image]

Comment: If it was in Russia I would assume this is for char-grilling of meat. Then again, how do you buy a bag of chipped wood, don't remember what's it for!?

Comment: Let us leave it at "blurred memory".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ut does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: It reads: "แม่หม้ายสะอื้น
สรรพคุณ
แก้ปวดหลัง ปวดเอว บำรุงกำลัง", this is some sort of a natural remedy for back pain. Not sure how to use it though.

Comment: "I'd like to return this back support pillow. Frankly, it just made things worse."